# Location based notifications in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, geolocation

I want to create a location based notification. Like this:

[Create local location based notifications in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28959201/create-local-location-based-notifications-in-swift)

So if I use `UILocalNotification`, how can I set `alertBody` to be the result of function that is executed only when the user enters the specific region?

Basically when a user enters a specific region, I want to perform a GET request and obtain some data which will be displayed in the notification, if required.

Also, when you register a geo location thing, do you need to have `locationManager` running the whole time, so you're getting `didLocationUpdate` calls?

Comment: Isn't most of this kind of answered in the other question - except maybe for the GET part, which can be looked up e.g. through Googling `Swift make GET request`? Can you clarify some more what you are stuck with?

Comment: @Pekka웃 No. I dont understand how I can make it trigger a function call which makes a GET, when the user enters the region.

Comment: Ah, I see, the example is literally for notifications only, there is nothing to put some other kind of action in.

Answer (score 3):

You want to use Core Location and create a `CLCircularRegion`. See the Xcode help system for more information.

### EDIT:

Specifically you want to use `CLLocationManager`. Take a look at the `startMonitoringForRegion` method. I suggest searching on "CLLocationManager class reference" in the Xcode help system and reading the entire introductory section, up to and including the section "Using Regions to Monitor Boundary Crossings", and then read up on `startMonitoringForRegion` and related classes and methods.

Here is a short excerpt from the introductory part of the "Using Regions to Monitor Boundary Crossings" section:

> To start region monitoring, configure the appropriate region object
> and pass it to the startMonitoringForRegion: method of your location
> manager. In iOS, registered regions persist between launches of your
> app. If a region boundary crossing occurs while your iOS app is not
> running, the system automatically wakes it up (or relaunches it) in
> the background so that it can process the event. In this case, the
> options dictionary passed to the
> application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method of your app delegate
> contains the key UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey to indicate
> that your app was launched because of a location-related event. During
> the relaunch process, you must recreate your location manager object
> and assign a delegate capable of handling region-related events. After
> you do that, the system delivers the region notification for which
> your app was launched. All of the regions you configured previously
> are made available in the monitoredRegions property of any location
> manager objects you create.
>
> Once you set up the location manager to monitor a circular region, you will get called when the user enters or exits the region.
> You can then perform your network request and generate a local
> notification if your app is not running in the foreground.

Note that if you're doing network operations from the background you'll need to ask for background time or you will likely be suspended before the response comes in.

Comment: Wont this mean the user has to have the app open? I was hoping to be able to do it when the user isn't using the app, but have it send them a notification when they enter a specific area. And does this mean I need to have `locationManager` running constantly? Because that would use a heap of battery.

Comment: No, the Core Location manager will give your app about enter/exit region notifications even if it is in the background, or not running at all.

Comment: The location manager manages things to conserve battery. It does not leave the GPS running at all times.

Comment: Ah, ok, I'll look into this then.

Comment: Do a search on "CLLocationManager class reference" in the Xcode help system and read the entire first part up to the section "Using Regions to Monitor Boundary Crossings".

Comment: There are a lot of things you have to get right in order for this to work. Make sure you set the correct keys in your info.plist that indicate you need location services in the background, and when you get launched in the background for a region notification, make sure you recreate your location manager object and set up a delegate so that you can receive notifications.

Comment: I do all this in the initial view controller right?

Answer (score -1):

ok I wanted to do something very similar so what I did is I only call notification to take place if I get something from server
below is the code hope this helps:
initialize with:

```
let center = unusernotificationcenter.current()
```

I am just taking a string value from firebase

```
var myStr: string?{
didSet{ status() }}
```

above is the variable which will be equal to the string I am getting from firebase real time database and as soon as it gets set status function will be called

```
func status(){
center.getnotificationsetting { (setting) in 
switch settings.alertsetting{
case .enabled:
if cllocationmanafer.locationservicesenabled() == true{
switch cllocationmanager.authrizationstatus(){
case .authrizedalways:
let content = unmutablenotificationcontent(){
content.title = "title"
content.body = "self.myStr! is what I am getting when I enter region"
let locTrigger = unlocationnotificationtrigger(region: self.shop, repeat: false)
let req = unnotificationrequest(identifier: "id", content: content, trigger: locTrigger)
self.center.add(req, withcompletionhandler: { (error) in 
if error != nil{ print(error!)}else{
print("success") } })
default:
print("location is req to trigger notification") } } else{
print("location service is not enabled") }
case default:
print("other cases") } } }
```